# /mnt/overlay and override in AEM

Tags: aem

It's clear to me ,what is resourceMerger and also clear about the theoretical concept of /mnt/overlay and /mnt/override.
But I want to know the use case of this.Is it to merge the resources from your code?

I am bit confused.Please help!!

Comment: Please refer to http://www.aemcq5tutorials.com/tutorials/sling-resource-merger-in-aem/ as it explains in detail the difference between merger and overlay and why you would do it. In short, merger saves you from a lot of copy/paste bad practice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use/understand AEM Sling Resource Merger, override and Overlay concepts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41688713/how-to-use-understand-aem-sling-resource-merger-override-and-overlay-concepts)

Comment: This answer is not satisfying me.Can u explain with a better example.

Comment: Quoted from answer: `The goals for using the Sling Resource Merger in AEM are to:

ensure that customization changes are not made in /libs.
reduce the structure that is replicated from /libs.`. If you are asking for use case, this is your use case for resource merger. You want to avoid duplication of tree structure in your components that have a supertype from a base component. A practical example would be to minimise component duplication on multi-tenant AEM deployment where different business requirements may require specific override of base components. HTH