# what is difference between extend, overlay and override component in aem

Tags: aem

What is the difference between Extending a component, overriding a component and overlaying a component. Can someone please explain with developer point of view

Comment: @i.net, Thank you for your response. But I didn't get clarity between how to override and overlay OOTB component .

Comment: Can you be more specific with your understanding of the concept? The override/overlay concepts are well discussed in other post I mentioned.

Comment: @i.net, can you tell me how to override OOTB component in my project. I'm learning aem. Please help me.

Comment: Just change the `sling:resourceSuperType` property of your component to override the behaviour of base component.

Comment: I have added more details in answer below to be more specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use/understand AEM Sling Resource Merger, override and Overlay concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41688713/how-to-use-understand-aem-sling-resource-merger-override-and-overlay-concepts)

Comment: @AnilJagtap may be help full https://aemvardhan.wordpress.com/2017/02/22/understand-aem-sling-resource-merger-override-and-overlay-concepts/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Extend and Overlay** are same. It's just a matter of terminology. Extending and overlaying involves copying the component from /libs/ (or other base library) to /apps node and changing the behaviour.

**Override** is similar to extend but the only difference is that you change the `sling:resourceSuperType` of the component so that it's behaviour completely changes (hence overridden).

More details can be found at:

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/develop/components/components-basics.html